# Collection fetch() parameters how to read in laravel

Tags: backbone.js, laravel, laravel-4

I want to fetch collection with parameter so i simply do :

```
 var collection = new App.Collections.Tasks
 collection.fetch({'title':'foo bar')
```

Now how can i read this the parameters in laravel ? i created taskController using php artisan and get standard :

```
 <?php

 class TasksController extends BaseController {


public function index()
{
    return Task::all();
}

    public function create()
{

}

public function store()
{
}

public function show($id)
{

}

public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

public function update($id)
{

}

public function destroy($id)
{

}

  }
```

in my router i have:

```
 Route::resource('tasks','TasksController');
```

now when i open localhost/tasks i get all tasks. but how and where i can get parameters of collection.fetch() ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In backbone app you have to do this (notice data parameter) :

```
 collection.fetch({ data: {sortby: "random"}});
```

In Laravel route or controller you just get that as input:

```
$sortby = Input::get('sortby');
echo $sortby;
```

Should display "random".

Comment: Thank you very very much - it works perfectly :) I spend 5 hours with uncle google and found nothing. Greetings.

Comment: Awesome! Great to hear you got it sorted out! On to a bigger and better apps =)